# How to find a SHA1 encrypted string from the 5-word encrypted hash in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, encryption, sha1, cryptojs

Say you're encrypting the string "alextoul" with CryptoJS.SHA1.

As explained in the source below you get an object that looks like that:

> CryptoJS.SHA1("alextoul") = {words: { 0: 1025575641 1: -2026381578 2: 1077518901 3: 1028391820 4:
>   1049226021 }}

Turns out if you convert this to a string you get:

> CryptoJS.SHA1("alextoul").ToString() = "3d210ad98737def64039a2353d4c038c3e89eb25"

Now what I'm trying to do is find the string above ("3d210ad98737def64039a2353d4c038c3e89eb25") from the 5 words but in Ruby.

> thefunctionineed(params[:words]) # Equal to "3d210ad98737def64039a2353d4c038c3e89eb25"

Source: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Hasher_Output

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to take the sha1 hash `3d210ad98737def64039a2353d4c038c3e89eb25` and turn it back into the string `'alextoul'`? What does this have to do with Ruby on Rails and iPhones?

Comment: No, I'm trying to find the full string ("3d210ad98737def64039a2353d4c038c3e89eb25") from the 5 words.

Answer (score 1):

Just reading the source:

https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src/core.js#181 -->

https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src/core.js#306 -->

```
function stringify(wordArray) {
        // Shortcuts
        var words = wordArray.words;
        var sigBytes = wordArray.sigBytes;

        // Convert
        var hexChars = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < sigBytes; i++) {
            var bite = (words[i >>> 2] >>> (24 - (i % 4) * 8)) & 0xff;
            hexChars.push((bite >>> 4).toString(16));
            hexChars.push((bite & 0x0f).toString(16));
        }

        return hexChars.join('');
    }
```

Then call

```
stringify(CryptoJS.SHA1("alextoul"))
```

Sorry I don't know ruby well enough to port that

Comment: I think the original poster wants a Ruby solution. Ok, never mind, I take it back :/